# How to find sub-parts of a .OBJ 3D model using three.js?

Tags: three.js, .obj

I need to implement a functionality where user can upload a OBJ 3D model and then I will show different sub-parts of that model in browser. (Same as https://www.sculpteo.com is doing.).

But I am unable to find sub-parts of OBJ model. I am using three.js to show OBJ model in browser.

Is there any way to find sub-parts to OBJ model using three.js?

I am sharing code to load OBJ model =>

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'path' );
mtlLoader.load( 'model.mtl', function( materials ) {
  materials.preload();

  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
  objLoader.setPath( 'path' );
  objLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object);
  });
});
```

Now I don't know how to find sub-parts of this "model.obj". Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved yet?

Answer (score 2):

OJBLoader returns (<strike>THREE.Object3D()</strike> (it was in r71)) THREE.Group() (r81) with children of THREE.Mesh.

You'll get sub-parts as child meshes of the object only if your .obj file has groups of objects. Without it, you'll get just a sinlge child mesh.
Read about [Wavefront .obj file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).
So, if your data of sub-parts grouped under

```
o [object name]
```

tag, then you'll have as many child meshes as you have "o" groups in your .obj file and then you can traverse.

**upd**#1: It also works with "g" tags.

```
g [group name]
```

The [example](http://west77.ru/content/r81/webgl_interactive_obj.html) based on "webgl_interactive_cubes" from Threejs.org, the data of sub-parts grouped with "g" tags (skull, uteeth, jaw, lteeth) in the .obj file

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for this post, seems like OBJLoader2 works better with `g` tags, I converted all my model files from `o` to `g` and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

When you load the objects you can do this inside your callback function :

```
   objLoader.load('yourUrl.obj', function (object) {
     object.traverse(function (child) {
       if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
         console.log(child);
         // here you can make what you want with the children of object
       }
     });
   });
```

Comment: Using raycaster, I can pick up the objects but my problem is how to find these separate objects in raycaster. Because in my case user is uploading .obj file.  So I don't know the names of sub-parts to pickup them.

Comment: @AshishKumar So what exactly do you want to do? Suppose the user loads an obj model. Then what do you need to do with the parts of it?

Comment: I need to show all parts as different objects in different renderers.

Comment: @AshishKumar and you do have a reference to the object user loads? you have assigned to a variable?

Comment: I save that user uploaded model on my server then I load it to browser using three.js.

Comment: @AshishKumar could you share the code of how you load it using three.js?

Comment: var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath( 'path' );
    mtlLoader.load( 'model.mtl', function( materials ) {
      materials.preload();

      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
      objLoader.setPath( 'path' );
      objLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object);
      });
    });

Comment: @AshishKumar you can use Object.traverse, see my update answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We can find number of parts using "object.traverse". "https://www.shapeways.com" and "https://www.sculpteo.com" are also doing same thing (I am not sure which javascript they are using.). But sub-parts calculated by three.js using object.traverse is coming more then both sites which seems incorrect to me.

Comment: @AshishKumar I didn't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Try uploading a model on https://www.shapeways.com and see parts count. After this calculate no. of parts using three.js "object.traverse". The count is different and the count shown by https://www.shapeways.com looks more correct. That is the problem. There should be another functionality in three.js to calculate sub-parts.

Comment: @AshishKumar are you sure that the model you are uploading has indeed subparts? It might be just one geometry, one mesh.

Comment: Yes my object has sub-parts and I can also find sub-parts using three.js "object.traverse" method but my parts count is coming more then the count "https://www.shapeways.com" and "https://www.sculpteo.com" is giving. This is looking incorrect to me. 

Kindly download any obj model (which has sub-parts) from internet  and then upload it on https://www.shapeways.com or https://www.sculpteo.com. After this calculate count of sub-parts using three.js. You will see the difference.

Comment: @AshishKumar is it a big difference or just 1-2 sub objects more?

Comment: My count is almost 2 times more then their. (1-2 more sub objects is also not correct)

Comment: @AshishKumar it might be a material problem. Do you upload also the .mtl file in shapeways?

Comment: No there is no option to upload .mtl on shapeways but when I am removing .mtl file from my code then also the count is not same.

Comment: @AshishKumar that's strange. Could you share the code you use in three.js to count sub-objects?

Comment: `var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(); objLoader.setPath( 'path_to_model' ); objLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) { var count = 0; object.traverse(function (child) { if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) { count++; } }); console.log(count); scene.add( object ); }, function(res) {}, function(err) {} );
`

Comment: @AshishKumar ok then the only thing I can think of is that shapeways.com make some kind of merge of geometries/meshes in their three.js code. Also, three.js creates more objects for materials (for examplemultimaterial objects) so that could also be an other reason.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Give @ThanosSar a medal

Comment: @CaipiDE :) :) .